# Number of Binary Search Trees with given right arm stretch

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

For a given array of distinct (unique) integers I want to know the number of BST in all permutations with right most arm of length k.
(If k = 3, root->right->right is a leaf node)

(At my current requirement, I can not afford an algorithm with cost greater than N^3)

Two identical BSTs generated from different permutations are considered different.

My approach so far is:

Assume a function:

```
F(arr) = {a1, a2, a3...}
```

where a1 is count of array with k = 1, a2 is count of array with k2 etc.

F(arr[1:n]) = for i in range 1 to n (1 + df * F(subarr where each element is larger than arr[i]))
Where df is dynamic factor (n-1)C(count of elements smaller than arr[i])

I am trying to create a dp to solve the problem

- Sort the array
- Start from largest number to smaller number
- dp[i][i] = 1
- for(j in range i-1 to 1) dp[j][i] = some func of dp[j][i-1], but I am unable to formulate

For ex: for arr{4, 3, 2, 1}, I expect the following dp

```
          arr[i]  4   3   2   1
                +---+---+---+---+
         k = 1  | 1 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
                +---+---+---+---+
         k = 2  | - | 1 | 3 |11 |
                +---+---+---+---+
         k = 3  | - | - | 1 | 6 |
                +---+---+---+---+
         k = 4  | - | - | - | 1 |
                +---+---+---+---+
verification(n!) 1    2   6   24
```

Any hint, suggestions, pointers or redirection to a good source where I can meet my curiosity is welcome.

Thank you.

edit: It seems I may need 3D dp array. I am working on the same.
edit: Corrected col 3 of dp

Comment: Thanks for all the helping hands. I have got the answer after thinking a little harder and putting more ink on papers. dp[j][i] = dp[j-1][i] * (i-1) + dp[j][i-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good new is that is you don't want the permutation but only their numbers, there is a formula for that. These are know as (unsigned) [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). The reason for that is that is that **the numbers appearing on the right arm of a binary search tree are the left to right minima**, that is the `i` such that the number appearing before `i` are greater than `i`. Here is a example where the records are underlined

```
 6 8 3 5 4 2 7 1 9
 _   _     _   _
```

This gives the tree

```
          6
    3           8
 2     5      7   9
1     4
```

Those number are know to count permutation according to various characteristics (number of cycles... ). It is know that maxima or minima are among those characteristics. .You can find more information on [Entry A008275](http://oeis.org/A008275) of the The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Now to answer the question of computing them. Let `S(n,k)` be the number of permutations of `n` numbers with `k` left to right minima. You can use the recurrence:

- `S(n, 0) = 0` for all `n`
- `S(n+1, k) = n*S(n, k) + S(n, k-1)`  for all `n>0` and `k>0`

Comment: Although it came after I had my answer, but your post surely gave me a good link to stirling numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly.

1. You do not need to sort an array. Since all number in you array are unique, you can assume that every possible subtree is a unique one.
2. Therefore you just need to count how may unique trees you can build having N - k unique elements, where N is a length of your array and k is a length of right most arm. In other words it will be number of permutations of your left subtree if you fix your right subtree to a fixed structure (root (node1 (node2 ... nodeK)))

Here is a way to calculate the number of binary trees of size N:

```
public int numTrees(int n) {

    int[] ut = new int[Math.max(n + 1, 3)];

    ut[1] = 1;
    ut[2] = 2;

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        int u = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            u += Math.max(1, ut[j]) * Math.max(1, ut[i - j - 1]);
        }
        ut[i] = u;
    }

    return ut[n];
}
```

it has O(n^2) time complexity and O(n) space complexity.

Comment: The question is about binary **search** trees, not regular binary trees

Comment: @Dukeling In contrast to ballanced trees BSTs can have any structure. It seems that if you have N elements you can arrange them in BST no matter what structure of the tree has. There for I assumed that you counting the number of unique trees is enough. If I have a flaw in my reasoning, please point on it, and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @IvanMushketyk Point 1, I accept, point 2 I can not completely agree. Or may be I am missing something.

Comment: @MohitJain Could you please explain in more details, why you do not agree with me? Is there any points I should clarify, or there any flaws in my reasoning that I miss?

Comment: @IvanMushketyk I mean I agree with your point that create all possible right trees and add rest of the numbers. But I can not start from tree, rather I need to start with array. Please recall "Two identical BSTs generated from different permutations of array are considered different". That means [2 1 3] and [2 3 1] are counted as 2. Although they result in just 1 tree.

Comment: @MohitJain "But I can not start from tree, rather I need to start with array." Sorry if I misunderstood you, but the all possible BSTs with same set of numbers will map to exactly same sorted array. BSTs have all numbers sorted and the only difference between them is structure of sub-trees,

Comment: @MohitJain If you have an BST with elements 1, 2 and 3 you can place them (1 (2 3)) or (2 (1 3)) or (3 (1 2)) etc. But notice that no matter what structure of the tree you chose elements in the tree will have the same order in in-order traversal. They are sorted in this specific BST way. Therefore the order of the elements is fixed and the only variable thing is the structure of the BST. That's why I assume that you need only to calculate the number of sub-trees with the specified number of elements.

Comment: I am really sorry. It seems I am not clear in phrasing my question. Let me try again.  
For numbers [1, 2, 3], there are six permutations.  
If I create BST for all permutations, I would end up with 6 BSTs (some of which are duplicates.  
RA mean right arm length  
[1 2 3] RA = 3,  
[1 3 2] RA = 2,  
[2 1 3] duplicate of [2 3 1] RA = 2,  
[3 1 2] RA = 1,  
[3 2 1] RA = 1.  
So Number of trees (or permutations) if k=1 is 2.  
Number of trees if k=2 is 3 (with 1 duplicate).  
Number of trees if k=3 is 1. (2 + 3 + 1 = 3!)  
This vector is same as column 3 of dp shown in my question.